# Ubuntu 20.04 Dual-boot Installation failed in MacBook

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, macbook

It is my first time installing Ubuntu in my new MacBook Pro. (MacBook 16 inch, Catalina 10.15.6) I have exactly followed the whole process from [a video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kRgKlcm1XPI) (except that I am installing Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and using balenaEtcher).

1. download the Ubuntu ISO
2. use balenaEtcher to make a bootable drive
3. partition my Mac (make Ubuntu and swap disk)
4. restart and pressed the option key
5. clicked on EFI Boot

[image: screenshot of boot options]

After I clicked the EFI Boot, it somehow restarts my MacBook...

I thought it was due to startup disk so I removed all the securities.

[image: screenshot of startup security]

However, it still shows this message after clicking the EFI Boot.

[image: screenshot of an error message]

So far, I have reinstalled my MacOS, made bootable drive following guide from official ubuntu website [command line](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick?_ga=2.182902054.1218755354.1599005514-1695592388.1599005514) , but it still gives me the [same error messages...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnbqD.jpg)

Is it a MacOS issue? or Is it my flash drive issue? (I have erased it to MS-DOS Fat with GUID partition map, but didn't work...)

Please save me to install this Ubuntu...

[What I see in the Booting mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DP3Sm.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please [edit] your question to explain what you mean by clicking on “EFIboot”. I can’t recall having such an option on any of my Macs. Have you verified your download or tried another method of creating the bootable drive? Have you checked the drive boots in another computer?

Comment: When I say EFI Boot, I refer to the the options that pops up when you restart mac and press the option key.  Just like this [image] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ziy7B.jpg)

I have so far tried with 1) command line 2) balenaEtcher to make a bootable drive. Before I tried, I have always erased the USB to MS-DOS Fat with GUID partition map. 

I have not check with other computers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you try the Windows option to boot using legacy BIOS? (Apple’s firmware calls any BIOS bootable drives Windows…) You should install Ubuntu in EFI mode if it’s possible but this could help us to check the drive is created correctly. By the way, it shouldn’t be necessary to format the USB to FAT as writing an ISO replaces the contents of the drive, including the format (file system).

Comment: Thank you the reply! :) I can confirm that the ISO has been successfully installed in the USB Drive as I have tries it in one of my friend't macbook (macbook air 13 with macos Big Sur)

What do you mean by "Windows option to boot using legacy BIOS"? Is there any reference I can follow through? Thank you :)

Comment: I just updated the image as "What I see in the Booting mode." As you can see, all I see is the Mackintosh and EFI Boot. I don't see Windows option.

Comment: @Melebius: Macs with the T2 chip do not have a legacy BIOS.

Comment: Check out https://t2linux.org/

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have been to the Apple's service center in Korea and the answer they gave me was I don't know and the possible reason for this is due to T2 chip that the Apple has put since 2017 Model (or 2018). So, as of now, no can do for dual-boot Ubuntu on Macbook pro that has T2 model.

Not sure whether Apple will make an software update to allow to boot this kind of external booting disk, but for those who are looking for a solution, go for Virtual Machine to get some work done in Ubuntu.

Comment: Check out https://t2linux.org/